# Save pulled data from MySQL table into another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query here pulling data from MySQL database. It's working great.But what am trying to do is save all the data pulled from the module table into another table. How could I go about this please ??  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
$coremoduleY1Query = "SELECT ID,title,credits FROM module WHERE ID = 'CS1101'
            UNION SELECT ID,title,credits FROM module WHERE ID = 'CS1105'
            UNION SELECT ID,title,credits FROM module WHERE ID = 'CS1106'
            UNION SELECT ID,title,credits FROM module WHERE ID = 'CS1107'
            UNION SELECT ID,title,credits FROM module WHERE ID = 'CS1108'
            UNION SELECT ID,title,credits FROM module WHERE ID = 'CS1109'";                                                                           


        $coremoduleY1Result = mysql_query($coremoduleY1Query);
        echo "<B> Core Modules </B>";                      
        while ($coremoduleRow = mysql_fetch_array($coremoduleY1Result)) {

                 $id = htmlentities($coremoduleRow['ID']);
                 $title = htmlentities($coremoduleRow['title']);
                 $credits = $coremoduleRow['credits'];

                 echo "<ul>" . $id . " " . $title .  " " . $credits . "</ul>";
       }   
       echo "<br />";
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for suggestion(s). It's well appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one why are you not querying like this:

```
SELECT ID,title,credits FROM module WHERE ID IN ('CS1101','CS1105','CS1106','CS1107','CS1108','CS1109')
```

And secondly you can do what you want totally in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO other_table (ID,title,credits)
SELECT ID,title,credits FROM module WHERE ID IN ('CS1101','CS1105','CS1106','CS1107','CS1108','CS1109')
```

Comment: @Petah Thanks. Never thought about doing my query the way you suggested,am not the best PHP coder yet,am on the learning scale.Thanks for the suggestion. The way you suggested is definitively faster.Thanks for the overall answer as well.Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

That question is a little strange in my eyes. 
If I am not totally mistaken all you ask for is: "use an INSERT statement".

You might want to shorten this into a single statement: 
INSERT INTO ... (col1,col2,...) (SELECT ... FROM module);